# Help me change this JS/Jquery Function to Dynamically Create Divs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, javascript

I have uploaded my code to JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TSM_mac/pnQEe/

I want to be able to type into the text inputs on the page, and click the "Add Div Type" button, and it will append (create) the div element inside of the div you click on (that has the class = "editable").

I have having difficulty making this code work. Can anyone find where I went awry?

### Code

```
var $currentInput = null;

$("#add_div1, #add_div2, #add_div3").click(function() {
    $currentInput = null;
    if ($currentInput == null) {
        $currentInput = $(this).prev();
        $("label").html($currentInput.attr("id"));
    }
});


var editid;
$("div.editable").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($currentInput == null) return;
    editid = $(this).attr("id");
    var adddiv = GetElements();
    $(this).append(adddiv);
    $("label").html("");
});

function GetElements() {
    if ($currentInput == null) return null;

    var value = $currentInput.val();

    if ($currentInput.attr("id") == "add_div1") return {
        "<div>"+value+"</div>"
    }
    if ($currentInput.attr("id") == "add_div2") return {
        "<div>"+value+"</div>"
    }
    if ($currentInput.attr("id") == "add_div3") return {
        "<div>"+value+"</div>"
    }
}
```

-

```
<input type="text" id="add-div1" value="Content of Div 1" />
<div id="add_div1">Add Div Type 1</div>
<input type="text" id="add-div1" value="Content of Div 2" />
<div id="add_div2">Add Div Type 2</div>
<input type="text" id="add-div1" value="Content of Div 3" />
<div id="add_div3">Add Div Type 3</div>



<div id="2" class="defaultclass editable">
    Add a Div Here
</div>
<div id="3" class="defaultclass editable">
     Add a Div Here
</div>
<div id="4" class="defaultclass editable">
    Add a Div Here
</div>

<label></label>
```

-

```
input { display: block; padding-top: 10px; }
#add_div1, #add_div2, #add_div3 { background: #c0c0c0; border: solid 1px #777; display: inline-block; }

.editable { border: solid 5px green; margin: 20px; background: blue; color: #fff; }
```

Regards,

Taylor

Comment: I know that if I just use $(this).append(adddiv) and change "adddiv" to "<div> Hello </div>" then it will work when I click. There is just something going on with the way that this is formatted:

"<div>"+value+"</div>"

Which doesn't allow it to work as the "adddiv" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one works now

http://jsfiddle.net/pnQEe/5/

(I added some `console.log` but now is commented out)

seems like your code is that you need to click the button and then click the div

Issue #1:  you have   `return {  ...  }`   It should be `{ return ... }` or just `return ...`

Issue #2: you have `add-div1` but the code checked against `add_div1` (underscore, not hyphen)

Also, I try not to have two elements with the same or similar id name as well. (such as `add-div1` for the text input, and `add_div1` for the button -- looks too similar.

Comment: Thank you! I see what your are saying. Thank you for modifying that code, it works great!

Comment: haha, you are welcome.  1 upvote plus accepted answer won't hurt... although I wonder why it usually is 0 upvote even when it is accepted answer.